# How do we handle console output in non-English languages?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839479/problem-with-postgres-for-loop?rq=1).

This question appears to have its debugging output in German, per its use of [fehler](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/Fehler.html).

Should it be edited to use the English translations, or left as-is?

Comment: That and the "Ich" at the beginning look like the only foreign bits in the question (I too would assume German, given the opening "Ich") and they really don't detract that much from the question. The "Fehler" may need some clarity, but the rest of the error seems clear enough to me. It even managed (at least one, to my limited knowledge, correct) answer(s) without the translation needed. The important part of the error is clear enough.

Comment: "I've got error: FEHLER: Syntax error near »FOR« LINE 1: ...dren WHERE children.categoryid = c1.category_fk ) FOR $2 I..." Also the "dren"

Comment: The "dren" is in actuality "...dren" or more accurately, "children", but cut off. If you find that bit of code from the code block, you'll note the "WHERE" is proceeded by "children" on the previous line. This form of punctuation is used both to show a cut in a sentence _and_ in words, by the way.

Comment: *or more accurately, "children" except cut off* - @Kendra -  The sound you hear is me sputtering in exasperation because I actually tried to look that up. Cue the sad trombone.

Comment: @BSMP That's alright, it took me a moment to realize it wasn't a German phrase myself. I'm sure it tripped up more than a few people. ;) I'd wager plenty of said people are native English speakers, to boot.

Comment: To increase understandability I'd translate those parts to English. Even if one might be able to understand the German parts, it still causes potential for confusion and leads to questions (qed).

Answer (score 9):

Leave it alone.  The fact that the error identifier is in a different language is irrelevant if the rest of the error is in English.

If the entire error message were in a non-English language, then I'd **request the OP to translate it**, and not try to translate it myself.  The onus is on the OP to ask the question in English, and the question is eligible to be put on hold until this is done.