# Whole console output in non-English

Tags: discussion, questions, english

*Found one similar question on meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311763/how-do-we-handle-console-output-in-non-english-languages/311899#311899).*
So I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791198/ubuntu-16-04-fingerprint-identification) on Triage.
On this question pretty much the whole console output is not English. The one linked on that other meta question is just a few words.
How would someone deal with this question?

Comment: I close voted as unclear.

Comment: I feel the answer is the same: it's the asker's responsibility to provide more information, to translate the error message to English. IMO translating an error message to English and searching for the English version of the error message, is part of the research when solving a bug.

Comment: And that's why localised error messages are such a terrible idea.

Comment: @user000001 I absolutely agree. I committed to a habit a while ago to use everything in English, it makes my life much easier.

Comment: Localized error messages are a terrible idea until the language chosen for the messages is not yours. The audience for error messages is "users", not "English-speaking folk".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How would someone deal with this question?

Close it as off-topic. Putting the console output aside for a second, the question wasn't about programming -- it was about configuring software, making it a better candidate for Super User.