# How could technical steps for improving non-English questions be more easily accessible?

Tags: discussion, english

Users of non-English system locales are having difficulties (see *[erreur](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=erreur)*, *[Fehler](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fehler)*, *[errore](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=errore)*, etc.) learning these prerequisites for asking great questions:

- Q: How to acquire logs/errors in English? A: Run again with English shell/session locale.
- Q: How do I switch locale to default in Bash? A: [Try `export LC_ALL=C`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do)
- Q: How do I switch locale to default in PowerShell? A: ???

Even though **easily explained** in both SO meta and SU non-meta, this information is **not easily accessible**, because:

1. Non-native speakers will try overly generic or imprecise terms and search engines cannot fully make up for that (*unlocalize* is so much better than *English language*, thanks @molnarm). I am certain that there is an answer somewhere that I have not yet found, can we find it and add some keywords?
2. It is not yet linked within [the meta FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow). Can we find a good answer and improve it, cross-reference it and/or use it in [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers)?
3. We became accustomed to (Google-)translating [as recommended here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311763/how-do-we-handle-console-output-in-non-english-languages). A few questions already contain well-meant, but poorly discoverable translations. Translating back and forth will deviate from the original. Can we do better by telling the OP how to acquire the original message, wherever possible, in favor of telling the OP to translate?
4. There is little automation, though it might work well. When I wrote this meta question, the duplicate finder suggested *[The easily accessible information on how to help non-English speakers use Stack Overflow is outdated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349385/the-easily-accessible-information-on-how-to-help-non-english-speakers-use-stack)* which is at least related. Could such features be part of the effort to guide users to resources that allow them to ask 100% English questions?

Comment: The answers to "*Advice for non-native English speakers*" are mostly about writing good English, not actual SO-specific advice.

Comment: At least the questions that have an error message with a number in them should be easily translateable, just type error and the number into google, possibly combined with the program/language it occured in and you should find plenty of hits.

Comment: "I am certain that there is an answer somewhere  ..." I'm not so certain, at least not for these examples. But I agree that there could a tag for it, something like non-english-output. SO itself is for people speaking English (at least a bit). There are localized versions of SO though.

Comment: @Luuklag I do not doubt that it is easy (I know in Bash it is), I doubt that we are doing the best job we can in letting users of non-English locales know.

Comment: Would it be constructive to ask the non-English user what locale they are using? Could that locale be included in an MCVE? My thinking is that if I can reproduce the problem using the given MCVE and locale, I can then change the locale and see the unlocalized errors and output. That should then lead to an edit and potentially a solution. These hints may also help the user who is asking a question to improve their question.

Comment: @Freiheit that could be a solution, but only if someone is willing to spend all that extra time on it. Good if you want to, but we shouldn't let that be the standard. Askers come here for help, so they should do the best job they can in facilitating answerers to come up with an answer. An English error message is part of that.

Comment: The dumbest thing they had me doing during programming studies was to learn all programming terms in my native language. Not only did I have to learn all terms twice, it was also harmful, for all the reasons listed in this question and more. The solution is to stop living in the 1800s, get some proper tools that use English, then take it from there. If you live in a backwards nation that enforces the use of your native language for programming, too bad - that country will fall far behind. Consider moving somewhere where irrational, nationalistic reasons don't block you from being productive.

Comment: This falls into the UX bugs and feature requests. Stack Overflow has a very poor track record of fixing them. You are wishing for a Unicorn.

Comment: @jww Lately I have been motivated to dedicate more time towards learning English just by the kind people who corrected my posts on SE. Taking a small step away from *"abscond with your filthy backwards languages!"* towards offering small but constructive guidance with potential for mutual benefit is a very welcome community effort, **with or without UX change**.

Comment: im using an english OS, only to localize my messages.. Programming is q business dominated by english anyway. So why encurage to not use english. Even though I agree, that searching gor localized error messages is a pain.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect an answer for 4. might achieve a reasonable *maintenance burden / site improvement* ratio if it is implemented as a minor extension to something already serving a closely related purpose. 
The [language checker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323249/3195057) is currently able to <strike>tell people to go away</strike> gently direct people to existing localized versions of SO:

[image: Detecting Cyrillic alphabet, the language checker suggests ru.stackoverflow.com.]

With a slightly expanded list of triggers & targets, it could also teach how to become better contributors here:

[image: Detecting German error messages, the language checker suggests improving the question by switching to default locale.]

Caveats:

- I do not know [how well feature performs for its original purpose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365580/do-we-have-statistics-on-how-often-people-asking-in-different-languages-get-into) (or how that will change with "Ask a question" wizard). Until then, my claim that this helps is highly speculative.
- It cannot happen before someone wielding the powers of proper English language solves 2. and creates a nice target for such link, possibly also a more appropriate link text.
- It can only catch quite specific search terms, as beyond a few obvious keywords it is not easy to distinguish people who do not know the language and people who merely do not know how to change their systems language.

Another argument against adding such hints: "use emphasis only where expected to be effective" - [as discussed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327035/3195057) - does in my understanding not quite apply for my proposal - the target audience is not that much unwilling to use English, they merely do not know their operating systems well enough.